# How to register a custom AppHistoryServerPlugin?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serviceloader

How can I create my own implementation of `AppHistoryServerPlugin` trait and provide it as a service through `ServiceLoader` to Apache Spark?

Note: This plugin class is inside a JAR which is in the class path of Apache Spark.

#### Source Directory Structure

```
.
└── main
    ├── resources
    │   └── META-INF
    │       └── services
    │           └── org.apache.spark.status.AppHistoryServerPlugin
    └── scala
        └── org
            └── apache
                └── spark
                    └── custom
                        └── ui
                            ├── CustomScalaHistoryListener.scala
                            └── CustomScalaHistory.scala
```

#### org.apache.spark.status.AppHistoryServerPlugin

#### org.apache.spark.custom.ui.CustomScalaHistory

```
package org.apache.spark.custom.ui

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener
import org.apache.spark.status.{AppHistoryServerPlugin, ElementTrackingStore}
import org.apache.spark.ui.SparkUI

import scala.collection.Seq

class CustomScalaHistory extends AppHistoryServerPlugin {
  override def createListeners(conf: SparkConf, store: ElementTrackingStore): Seq[SparkListener] = {
    System.out.println("Inside Listener CustomScalaHistory intruder")
    List(CustomScalaHistoryListener)
  }

  override def setupUI(ui: SparkUI): Unit = {
    System.out.println("custom UI is set up CustomScalaHistory intruder")
  }
}
```

#### CustomScalaHistoryListener

```
package org.apache.spark.custom.ui

import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListener

object CustomScalaHistoryListener extends SparkListener with Logging {
  logInfo("LogInfo Inside CustomScalaHistoryListener intruder")
  println("Inside CustomScalaHistoryListener intruder")
}
```

#### pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>intruder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--JettyUtils in spark core uses this below dependency , do not remove this otherwise you cant compile your project-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF/</directory>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>

            <!-- the Maven compiler plugin will compile Java source files -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- the Maven Scala plugin will compile Scala source files -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

To build my package I run

```
mvn clean compile package
```

The resulting package also had `org.apache.spark.status.AppHistoryServerPlugin` in `META-INF/services`.

Finally I have put the JAR in `--jars` while doing `spark-submit` with `yarn-client` but Spark is not picking my `CustomScalaHistory` class.

Answer (score 1):

That's fairly easy :) Just have a look at the usage of the one and only known implementation of the trait, i.e. [SQLHistoryServerPlugin](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/ui/SQLHistoryServerPlugin.scala).

I'd also recommend reading up on Java's [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html):

> A service provider is identified by placing a provider-configuration file in the resource directory `META-INF/services`. The file's name is the fully-qualified binary name of the service's type. The file contains a list of fully-qualified binary names of concrete provider classes, one per line.

With that, you should easily find the provider-configuration file [META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.status.AppHistoryServerPlugin](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.status.AppHistoryServerPlugin) with the only line that is to register the plugin.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ui.SQLHistoryServerPlugin
```

Your plugin should do the same, i.e. create a jar file with `META-INF/services/org.apache.spark.status.AppHistoryServerPlugin` that gives the fully-qualified class name of the plugin. Place the file on the driver's CLASSPATH and it should be enough.

Comment: thanks for the response, I was doing same but couldn't get any luck and that's why I asked the above question here.

Comment: If you wish, I can add code and steps I followed in my question.

Comment: _"I was doing same but couldn't get any luck"_ please elaborate on what you expected and the steps you followed, esp. how did you "install" the plugin.

Comment: Just an idea...change the default `SQLHistoryServerPlugin` and see if the changes get picked up.

Comment: I have added code in question, any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Wait... _"Then: I have put the jar in --jars while doing spark-submit"_ Why are you using the plugin with `spark-submit` not `history-server`?! What do you expect from such a plugin?